# dplyr to bring in both the columns on which join is made

Tags: r, dplyr

say I have these two Data Sets , each having one column say FirstName and Name.
I want to apply a left join and see the results such that the resulting table appears as FirstName (from left table) , Name(from right table), while left joining on FirstName = Name.

Problem i encounter is that the end result of the left_join is one single column , which is FirstName, whereas i want to see the column on which was joined as well. Any idea how to achieve that?

```
t1 <- data.frame(FirstName= c('a','b','c','d'))
t2 <- data.frame(Name= c('a','b','c'))

library(dplyr)
t1%>%
  left_join(t2, c('FirstName'  = 'Name'))
```

as you see the result of the above is one single column , whihc is Firstname. it automatically omits the Name column from the other table and that is what i dont want it do.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you are asking does not really make sense to me: after the left-join, by definition the two columns will be identical. Perhaps there's more to this problem then this simplified example is presenting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a copy of the name column before joining

```
t1 <- data.frame(FirstName= c('a','b','c','d'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
t2 <- data.frame(Name= c('a','b','c'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
t1 %>%
  left_join(mutate(t2, Name2 = Name), c('FirstName'  = 'Name2'))
#  FirstName Name
#1         a    a
#2         b    b
#3         c    c
#4         d <NA>
```